# Multiple target variables regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I have a dataframe where these are my predictors.

```
min_time   max_time cluster_label  Day  Week
6000       9000           2        0    3
7000       9000           1        3    3
3000       5300           3        2    4
5000       6000           2        5    4
..
```

Using those features, I need to predict 4 features( target variables or y1,y2,y3,y4)

```
route_count   Delivieres          Distance     TotalTime

18           22                    290           3500
22           21                    334           5400
19           23                    503           3900
20           44                    674           4000
21           45                    398           6600
```

how can I do this? This is what I have tried so far, but I'm not sure if a random forest can output prediction of multiple variables

```
from sklearn.metrics import,accuracy_score,mean_absolute_error,mean_squared_error
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( 
                        X, y, test_size = 0.30, random_state = 101)
rfg = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100,criterion="mae")
rfg.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = rfg.predict(X_test)
rfg.score(X_test, y_test)
```

Comment: What do you mean "*I'm not sure*"? What do you get in `y_pred`?

Answer (score -1):

[`MultiOutputRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor.html) can achieve this. Simply use it as a wrapper.

```
from sklearn.metrics import,accuracy_score,mean_absolute_error,mean_squared_error
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( 
                        X, y, test_size = 0.30, random_state = 101)
rfg = MultiOutputRegressor(RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100,criterion="mae"))
rfg.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = rfg.predict(X_test)
rfg.score(X_test, y_test)
```

Comment: RF regressor can be natively used with multiple outputs without invoking `MultiOutputRegressor` - see the [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_random_forest_regression_multioutput.html) in the documentation.